# Convert Func<T1, T2> to Func<T2, bool>

Tags: c#, function, linq

Below is not the full code, but hope it's enough.

I want to pass a property Func and a value to a method, and return myself an object from a list where property is equal to value.

I have written this method

```
public static object IsLookupName<TEntity, TProperty>(Func<TEntity, TProperty> function, string value)
    {
          List<TEntity> entities = dbSet.ToList()
          var entity = entities.FirstOrDefault(function == value) //<= problem
          return entity;
    }
```

I call it like this:

```
.IsLookupName(x => x.CountryCode, "GB")
```

How can I apply this TProperty Func to get FirstOrDefault that requires `Func<TSource, bool> predicate`

Comment: Something like this: `var entity.FirstOrDefault(item => string.Equals(function(item)?.ToString(), value));`: you call the labda `function` over `item` of type `TEntity`, get `Property` which you convert into `string` and compare with `value`

Comment: Your `function` is a "selector". It just projects from one data type to another; if you want to compare the result of that selector with some value, you need to _invoke_ the selector, then do the comparison. With `FirstOrDefault()`, that means you need a second lambda that will do the invocation and comparison. See duplicate (the answer of which uses `Where()` instead of the `FirstOrDefault()` overload that takes a predicate, but otherwise is exactly the same as your scenario).